# FormArray : Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute in angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formarray

I created a form using the reactive and presentation form. When I invoke the fields for the submission form, this gives me the error.

this Erorr :

> Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

```
    addProductFG:FormGroup;
  cats:Category[];
  subCats:Category[];
  PD:Productdetail[];
  selectedCat:number;
  valueIngrident=new FormArray([]);
  public loading=false;

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder,private productService:ProductinfoService,private catService:CategoryService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading=true;
    this.InitialFrom();
    this.GetMainCat();
  }

  public CreateValueFiled(PD:Productdetail[]){
      PD.map(element => {
        this.valueIngrident.push(
          new FormGroup({
            infoId:new FormControl(element.id),
            value:new FormControl('')
          })
        )
      });
  }

  public GetMainCat(){
    this.catService.GetMainCat().subscribe(
      res=>{
        this.cats=res;
        this.loading=false;
      }
    )
  }

  get ValueFormControl(){
      return  this.addProductFG.get('values') as FormArray;
  }

  public InitialFrom():FormGroup{

    this.addProductFG=this.fb.group({
      productTitle:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      productName:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      color:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      productImageName:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      price:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      gurantyMonth:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      gurantyCompanyName:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      values:this.valueIngrident
    })
    return this.addProductFG;
  }
  public ChangeSubCat(id:number){
    this.loading=true;
      this.catService.GetSubCatByCatId(id).subscribe(
          res=>{
            this.subCats=res;
            this.loading=false;
          }
        )
  }

  public ChangeFormByType(id:number){
    this.loading=true;
      this.productService.GetPCIBySubId(id).subscribe(
        res=>{
          this.PD=res,
          this.CreateValueFiled(this.PD),
          this.loading=false;
        }
      )
  }
```

and in HTML :

```
       <div formArray="values">
                <div *ngFor="let valueCtrl of ValueFormControl.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <div  class="form-inline lbin">
                        <label>g </label>
                        <input formControlName="value" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and And this is my sample code in stackblitz [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5nskq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Whats the Problem ? How Can I Solve This problem ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `formArrayName` instead of `formArray`:

```
<div formArrayName="values">
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwrlra?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Also please keep your variables in sync:

**ts**

```
AddP: FormGroup; // why upper case?
```

html

```
[formGroup]="addP"
```

Javascript is case-sensitive language